# Simpler way of sorting list of lists indexed by one list in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a list of two lists, where the elements in the two lists are pairs.

I want to sort the lists by the second element in these pairs.

For example if I have

```
a_list = [[51132, 55274, 58132], [190, 140, 180]]
```

and want

```
sorted_list = [[55274, 58132, 51132], [140, 180, 190]]
```

Is there a simpler way than the following in Python2.7?

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_list = map(list, zip(*sorted(map(list,zip(*a_list)), key=itemgetter(1))))
```

Best regards,
Øystein

Comment: Please make clearer how you want the lists to be sorted.

Comment: what is pattern in your sorting ?

Comment: so....ummmm, sort the second list, and put the positions of the elements in the first one to mirror the shifts in position in the second list?

Comment: Sort one list and swap elements in other lists relativly to indeces of sorted list :)

Comment: I think you can drop the inner `map`, apart from that it looks okay to me.

Comment: The only solution i could come up with looks exactly the same as yours :zip(*sorted(zip(*a_list), key=lambda x : x[1])) . The question is, why work with 2 lists and not a list of tuples if the items have a relation with each other ?

Comment: The reason I have the two lists is just that I get these lists from an API to another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit reluctant to post this as an answer, but why not, actually?

No, there is no simpler way to achieve your sort in Python -- except that you can drop that inner `map`:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*a_list), key=itemgetter(1))))
[[55274, 58132, 51132], [140, 180, 190]]
```

It may seem a bit convoluted at first (though not as much as *with* that additional `map`), but actually it's totally clear: You *zip* the list, *sort* by the second element, and *zip* it back. Everyone who knows Python should understand what the code does.

If you want to make it even clearer, either add a line comment describing what the sort does, or wrap it inside a function with a descriptive name and the same or a more extensive comment.

Comment: It might help to give each of the three phases its own line, so you can give the intermediate results meaningful names or comment each phase separately.

Answer (score 1):

What you want according to my understanding is to sort each pair depending on the second element of the pair; that is to say, the ordering of the second element (of the pair) is to determine the ordering of the first element. The following code uses the corresponding position of the second element as the sorting key:

**EDIT:** I have made a revision that should solve the problem with duplicate elements, thanks for pointing that out:

```
class _Value:
    def __init__(self, pos, val):
        self.pos, self.val = pos, val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.val < other.val


a_list = [[51132, 55274, 58132], [190, 140, 180]]
a_list = [[_Value(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(l)] for l in a_list]

sorted_list = [sorted(l, key=lambda x: a_list[1][x.pos]) for l in a_list]
sorted_list = [[x.val for x in l] for l in sorted_list]
assert sorted_list == [[55274, 58132, 51132], [140, 180, 190]]
```

Comment: Thx, this answers my questions. But I'm not sure it's that much simpler though :)

Comment: The use of `index` causes quadratic performance degradation on large inputs and incorrect sort results when the input contains duplicates.

Comment: Better. It's still more complicated than necessary, though. I'm not sure why you bothered with the `_Value` class.